# What is step s07 in GCP Dataflow's Processing stuck in step s07 for at least 05m00s without outputting or completing in state finish

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I got this error in dataflow:

```
Processing stuck in step s07 for at least 05m00s without outputting or completing in state finish at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method) at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175) at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Signaller.block(CompletableFuture.java:1693) at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.managedBlock(ForkJoinPool.java:3323) at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.waitingGet(CompletableFuture.java:1729) at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1895) at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.MoreFutures.get(MoreFutures.java:57) at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.fn.control.RegisterAndProcessBundleOperation.finish(RegisterAndProcessBundleOperation.java:330) at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:85) at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.fn.control.BeamFnMapTaskExecutor.execute(BeamFnMapTaskExecutor.java:125) at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.process(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1320) at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.access$1000(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:151) at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker$6.run(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1053) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

There errors continues even for `03h50m00s`, so I think my dataflow job really stucks. But I don't know what `s07` refer to and cannot identify which step cause the problem? What is the naming tradition in Dataflow's steps? Any ways to find what's the issue?

Comment: You can find step #7 in dataflow logs, there will be structure of steps from the top level till the bottom

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways Dataflow pre-processes pipelines is to split them into steps, each of which contains multiple transforms from your original pipeline. Some of the logs that get output by Dataflow are descriptions of the steps that were created and what transforms are in them, so you may be able to find this by searching for `s07` in your logs.